# Bootstrap Modal Dialog is auto scroll browser to top when open through JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am opening a delete confirmation bootstrap modal dialog, everything is fine but when I open it through `jquery`, it scrolls the browser to top which I want to restrict. I want the same browser position when I open/close model window. I am using `bootstrap v 3.1.1, jquery 1.12.4, ASP.NET MVC5`

I have searched on the web but could not find the same problem that I am facing

```
bootstrap modal 

<div class="modal fade" id="DeleteConfirmation">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h4>Delete Record</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Are You Sure To Delete This Record.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="r">Cancel</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ConfirmDelete()">Confirm</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


jquery to open modal dialog:

  var DelRecord = function (TransactionId) {
            $("#TrnId").val(TransactionId);
            $("#DeleteConfirmation").modal("show");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the default behavior of anchor tag as with `href` set to `#` the browser scrolls to top of page. You can write you js function like:

```
var DelRecord = function (TransactionId,event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#TrnId").val(TransactionId);
            $("#DeleteConfirmation").modal("show");
        }
```

and from where you are calling should be like:

```
<a onclick="DelRecord(transactionId,event);">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Now there is another problem that when i save record from model dialog, its saved and close successfully but that record which i modified is not showing in the grid because i have removed the line **window.location.href = "/Home/index";** after data success in jquery. if i add this line then grid is updated   but it again scrolls browser window to top. how to show only updated values in record instead of refreshing whole grid. Thanks